# forEach tag doesn't know how to iterate over attribute JSP

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jstl

I'm having a List wich returns values from a database and i get it in a servlet where i assign it to a attribute and forward it to a jsp page where i loop through it.

And i encouter this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
```

class containing methods wich returns List

```
public class DataModel {

private DataSource dataSource;


public DataModel(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public List<Student> getStudents() throws ServletException, SQLException{

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();

        statement = connection.createStatement();

        String sql = "select * from student order by last_name";

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while(resultSet.next()) {

            String firstName = resultSet.getString("first_name");
            String lastName = resultSet.getString("last_name");
            String email = resultSet.getString("email");

            Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, email);
            students.add(student);

        }

        return students;
    }  finally {
        close(connection, statement, resultSet);
    }

}

private void close(Connection connection, Statement statement, ResultSet resultSet) {
    try {
        if(connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
        if(statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if(resultSet != null) {
            resultSet.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {


    }

}
```

}

My class containing
my servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/serveLET")
public class serveLET extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private DataModel dataModel;

@Resource(name="jdbc/web_student_tracker")
private DataSource dataSource;



@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.init();

    try {
        dataModel = new DataModel(dataSource);
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}



protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        List<Student> students = dataModel.getStudents();
        request.setAttribute("list-students1", students);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/page.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

JSP file code:

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
 <c:forEach var="tempStudents" items="${list-students1}">
 <tr>
 <td>${tempStudents.firstName }</td>
 <td>${tempStudents.lastName }</td>
 <td>${tempStudents.email }</td>
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

I have been spending a good amount of time into fixing this error with no solutions so far. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: `${list-students1}` is `${list - students1}`, i.e. the result of subtracting value of `students1` from value of `list`, assuming those are both *numeric* values. I suggest you rename the attribute to only use valid *identifier* names, e.g. replace `-` with `_`, though why not just call it `students`?. --- Since the `var` is one element from that list, it would be *singular*, so `student` would be better than `tempStudents`.

Comment: I'm sure you've figured out that `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>` basically means that the object in the `<c:forEach ...>` tag is not something that is iterable.   But looking at your code, it should looks like that items value should be a List.  Can you just print out the value of `list-students1`.  Use either `<p>${list-students1}</p>` or `<c:out value="${list-students1}"/>` to see what the object type is?